# Using openmpi and eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, openmpi

i want to ask if anyone knows a way to run a program that uses openmpi in eclipse. I am newbie using openmpi(in Java) that from the manual and examples, to run a program on openmpi you must do:

> $ mpirun  java

The problem is that i use AspectJ in this work, so i don really know exactly how to use mpirun and aspectj. So if anynone knows how to use mpirun with aspectj or start mpirun(with the number of processes i want) on main method or something let me know.

Comment: Eclipse supports parallel programming via [PTP](http://www.eclipse.org/ptp/) (Parallel Tools Platform).

Comment: Already download it. I am checking it out.thanks